# embed PHP in react js

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

I'm adding react.js to a section of my app and am trying to embed some php code into react.js in order to not have to rewrite my whole backend which I had written in php. The idea would be something like the following:

```
...render(){
  return(
    <h1><?php echo "hello world"; ?></h1>
  )
}...
```

Unfortunately, this does not compile. I have tried every possible permutation I can think of and nothing will work, yet I feel this must be possible. Thanks!

Felix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: interesting I'll check that out

Comment: Why would you expect this to work? That looks like a React component in a JavaScript file. PHP is designed to generate static HTML markup and wouldn't ever normally work if you embed it in a JS file.

Comment: I don't know much about react but the xml-like syntax led me to posit that it could. My goal is to write the front end of this section of my app in react rather than js/jquery (I have never practically used react before). What I am really hoping for is to loop through data fetched from the server in html blocks (for example to put each item in an array in a header)

Comment: your PHP parts can be switched to be an ajax call to your backend that returns either string of a component or json data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want server side rendering? Check it out  [react-php-v8js](https://github.com/reactjs/react-php-v8js)

Answer (score 0):

You *could* have PHP output your JS but you absolutely positively shouldn't. You could also make ajax calls like everyone else to fetch data from external sources such as a PHP script.

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
...componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://example.com/data.php")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => this.setState(result));
}...

...render() {
    return(
       <div>{this.state.result && this.state.result.foo}</div>
    );
}...
```

You're going to need to rebuild your current HTML output from PHP as React components. PHP now becomes a web service that looks something like this:

`<?php
// Business logic goes here:
$data=new stdClass();
$data->name="Uzebeckatrente";
$data->foo="bar";
echo json_encode($data);`

Lumen/Laravel is my personal choice of PHP platforms for web services.